# What are differences between mixins and utils in programming?

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

As I have seen these two concepts in different programming languages like python, dart. Sometimes I mixed up these two as one thing. are these two are similar or different?

Comment: I see mixin as kind of class-specific util, which is useful in dependent context (like, in some part of business logic). And utils, imo, is something general, that you can use in any part of your app (maybe working with django user or with strings in general)